# Regular Expression (find matching characters in order)

Tags: python, regex

Let us say that I have the following string variables:

```
welcome = "StackExchange 2016"
string_to_find = "Sx2016"
```

Here, I want to find the string `string_to_find` inside `welcome` using regular expressions. I want to see if each character in `string_to_find` comes in the same order as in `welcome`.

For instance, this expression would evaluate to `True` since the `'S'` comes before the `'x'` in both strings, the `'x'` before the `'2'`, the `'2'` before the `0`, and so forth.

Is there a simple way to do this using regex?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is rather trivial. The `.*` character combination matches 0 or more characters. For your purpose, you would put it between all characters in there. As in `S.*x.*2.*0.*1.*6`. If this pattern is matched, then the string obeys your condition.

For a general string you would insert the `.*` pattern between characters, also taking care of escaping special characters like literal dots, stars etc. that may otherwise be interpreted by regex.

Answer (score 3):

This function might fit your need

```
import re
def check_string(text, pattern):
    return re.match('.*'.join(pattern), text)
```

`'.*'.join(pattern)` create a pattern with all you characters separated by `'.*'`. For instance

```
>> ".*".join("Sx2016")
'S.*x.*2.*0.*1.*6'
```

Comment: good answer, except I'd suggest using .search() instead of .match() since match only matches starting from the beginning of the string

Answer (score 2):

Use wildcard matches with `.`, repeating with `*`:

```
expression = 'S.*x.*2.*0.*1.*6'
```

You can also assemble this expression with `join()`:

```
expression = '.*'.join('Sx2016')
```

Or just find it without a regular expression, checking whether the location of each of `string_to_find`'s characters within `welcome` proceeds in ascending order, handling the case where a character in `string_to_find` is not present in `welcome` by catching the `ValueError`:

```
>>> welcome = "StackExchange 2016"
>>> string_to_find = "Sx2016"
>>> try:
...     result = [welcome.index(c) for c in string_to_find]
... except ValueError:
...     result = None
...
>>> print(result and result == sorted(result))
True
```

Comment: I think he doesn't neccesarily mean the 2016 word is glued together.

Comment: How about `'.*'.join(string_to_find)`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually having a sequence of *chars* like `Sx2016` the pattern that best serve your purpose is a more specific:

```
S[^x]*x[^2]*2[^0]*0[^1]*1[^6]*6
```

You can obtain this kind of check defining a function like this:

```
import re
def contains_sequence(text, seq):
    pattern = seq[0] + ''.join(map(lambda c: '[^' + c + ']*' + c, list(seq[1:])))
    return re.search(pattern, text)
```

This approach add a layer of complexity but brings a couple of advantages as well:

1. It's the fastest one because the regex engine walk down the string only once while the dot-star approach go till the end of the sequence and back **each time a `.*` is used**. Compare on the same string (~1k chars):

   - [Negated class](https://regex101.com/r/aC8dE9/2) -> 12 steps
   - [Dot star](https://regex101.com/r/bN0gW9/1)     -> 4426 step
2. It works on multiline strings in input as well.

**Example code**

```
>>> sequence = 'Sx2016'
>>> inputs = ['StackExchange2015','StackExchange2016','Stack\nExchange\n2015','Stach\nExchange\n2016']
>>> map(lambda x: x + ': yes' if contains_sequence(x,sequence) else x + ': no', inputs)
['StackExchange2015: no', 'StackExchange2016: yes', 'Stack\nExchange\n2015: no', 'Stach\nExchange\n2016: yes']
```