# Condition in Python with letters in a specific order

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to find words in a corpus that have letters (specifically aeiouy) that appear in the words in that order (like facetiously). I have the following code so far, but am struggling on how to get it to have the condition that they need to be in the following order.

```
english = nltk.corpus.words.words()
words = [w for w in english if re.search(r'[aeiouy]',w)]
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression (find matching characters in order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391633/regular-expression-find-matching-characters-in-order)

Comment: It gets me closer. It still mixes letters, aeiouy still aren't in that specific order, but it is closer.

Comment: Would this be considered a matched word? facietiously (note extra i between c and e). Can you provide an example that currently mixes letters?

Answer (score 1):

#### Manually building the regex pattern

- Try `re.search(r'a[b-zB-Z]*e[b-df-zB-DF-Z]*i[b-df-hj-zB-DF-HJ-Z]*o[b-df-hj-np-zB-DF-HJ-NP-Z]*u[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]*y',w)` to allow for some (eventual) characters ([a-zA-Z]) between you letters.

  Ugly is n't it.
- But if you are beforehand sure that all characters are in [a-zA-Z], it can be simplified :
  `re.search(r'a[^a]*e[^ae]*i[^aei]*o[^aeio]*u[^aeiou]*y',w)`

#### Code building the pattern

- The following code builds the regex pattern

  ```
  >>>import itertools as it
  >>>seq = "aeiouy"
  >>>pattern = ''.join(it.chain(*[(c, '[^' + seq[0:i+1] + ']*') for i,c in enumerate(seq[:-1])], seq[-1]))
  >>>print(pattern)
  a[^a]*e[^ae]*i[^aei]*o[^aeio]*u[^aeiou]*y
  ```
- To sum it up

  ```
  # other imports
  import itertools as it
  import regex as re

  # words list 
  #english = nltk.corpus.words.words()
  english  = ["facietiously", "aeiouy", "aeioauy"] # mockup, note the second 'a' in the last string

  # the sequence
  seq = "aeiouy"
  " compiling the pattern for efficiency 
  seq_re = re.compile(''.join(it.chain(*[(c, '[^' + seq[0:i+1] + ']*') for i,c in enumerate(seq[:-1])], seq[-1])))

  words = [w for w in english if seq_re.search(w)]

  print(words)
  ```

  Output: note the filtering of the last string of the word list:

  ```
  ['facietiously', 'aeiouy']
  ```

Comment: @Eddie14, updated, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Yes that updated version worked. That should be perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about `re.search('a[^iouy]*e[^aouy]*i[^aeuy]*o[^aeiy]*u[^aeio]*y', w, re.I)`

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimal way to do it without having to use RegEx:

```
def verifyString(s):
    current_vowel = 'a'
    vowels= 'aeiouy'
    for c in s:
        if c==current_vowel:
            if len(vowels)==1:
                return True
            vowels = vowels[1:]
            current_vowel = vowels[0]
    return False
```

If you want the order to be strict, you can use:

```
def verifyStringStrict(s):
    current_vowel = 'a'
    vowels= 'aeiouy'
    for c in s:
        if c in vowels:
            if c==current_vowel:
                if len(vowels)==1:
                    return True
                vowels = vowels[1:]
                current_vowel = vowels[0]
            else:
                return False
    return False
```

You will have:

```
verifyString('saseqiqoqusyq') #True
verifyStringStrict('ssasdediqqodudyd') #True
verifyString('zazezizzudozyz') #False
verifyStringStrict('daezizzuzozyz') #False
verifyString('waewwiwuowuwcyd') #True
verifyStringStrict('waeiwuwowuwxyx') #False
```